# Missing entrypoints.json when installing webpack encore bundle from scratch on Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, webpack, webpack-encore

Did the following to create a new Symfony 6 project:

```
cd /var/www/html
composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton <project>
cd <project>
composer req --dev symfony/profiler-pack
composer req symfony/apache-pack
composer req maker doctrine twig
```

so far nothing special. Then

`php bin/console make:controller`

to create a simply Home-Controller

Then I wanted to install Bootstrap with Encore Bundle according to https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/installation.html

Now when I open the website I get the error:

An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Could not find the entrypoints file from Webpack: the file "/var/www/html//public/build/entrypoints.json" does not exist.").

It's this line/command causing the problem in **templates/base.html.twig** (line 9) :

{{ encore_entry_link_tags('app') }}

Just as a hint: There is not only entrypoints.json missing - but the whole folder *public/build* does not exist at all.

What do I have to do?

Comment: Did you also do the action written here https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/simple-example.html ? Most important `build the assets`.

Comment: You probably did not run `yarn watch` or `yarn build`. Running it will compile your assets and dump them in `public/build`

Comment: yarn watch gives me a new error: Command "watch" not found.

Answer (score 0):

If the `public/build` folder is empty, that means you haven't done any assets compilation.
From [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/simple-example.html#configuring-encore-webpack) you can see that to compile assets you have to run e.g. `yarn dev`.

Comment: $yarn dev
yarn run v1.22.19
warning package.json: No license field
error Command "dev" not found.

Comment: Do you have anything in package.json file? Symfony flex should download it for you. It seems you either haven't followed the installation instructions or denied the flex recipe or edited the package.json file. From documentation `All of these commands - e.g. dev or watch - are shortcuts that are defined in your package.json file.`

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the direction. As I wrote: it's from scratch. I did not change a single thing manually as I relied on the automation (otherwise why using package managers at all?). package.json content: {
  "devDependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.3"
  }
}

Comment: The command `composer require symfony/webpack-encore-bundle` should add the package.json file with all those aliases. If it didn't, maybe try to delete package.json file completely, run `composer remove symfony/webpack-encore-bundle` and do it again. You need couple of things in the package.json file other than aliases, for example dependency on `@symfony/webpack-encore` .

Comment: Also do you have `"symfony/flex"` dep in your `composer.json` file?

Comment: Ok. We are getting closer. Now package.json has much more entries  - including watch and build. I wonder which of the other packges mixed up with it. But now I get a new error: yarn build yarn run v1.22.19 $ encore production --progress /bin/sh: 1: encore: not found - wasn't encore included when installing the bundle? Do I have to install it manually?

Comment: Yep I would suggest to go step by step from the page https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/installation.html and continue with https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/simple-example.html You can find better explanation there.
Basically you need `yarn install`, because you haven't installed the webpack/encore. `yarn dev` is just an alias to `encore dev`.

Answer (score 0):

After installing it with different methods (composer, yarn, npm etc.) using both Apache and symfony server and always running into the same error I had to use this command to (re)build the necessary folders and files to (at least) not run into the error again.

```
yarn build
```